# How to use removefromsuperview()?

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to remove self.view.subviews in UI interface.

I tried with view.removeFromSuperview(), It removes entier UI view.

Comment: You have to get that `subview`, one you get that subview let's say `mySubView`, then you can use this property like `mySubView.removeFromSuperview()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a view as a subview give it a tag and then remove that specific subview using that tag:

```
// Adding subview on view
let subviewOne = UIView()
subviewOne.tag = 123
self.view.addSubview(subviewOne)

// Removing subview from view
// First find out the subview you want to remove

for subview in view.subviews {
    if subview.tag == 123 {
         subview.removeFromSuperview() // Remove the added subview
    }
}
```